# c# mvc display data from webapi every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am developing a small application. I want to cycle through records from my api and display one of the record in the view every 10 seconds.

Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: without using bi-directional communication channel (something like websocket), I think your client side can use the so-called ***polling*** to request the data and update the page. It's just simple like that. The page can be totally reloaded by re-requesting the whole URL or partly updated using AJAX.

Comment: setInterval works. However, for a better user experience you should consider using real time application solutions like SignalR or websockets. They are very different technologies and have a learning curve. But if you want a greate solution, then you need to learn them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setInterval function in Javascript:

```
setInterval(function(){ MyFunctionToDoTheWork();} , 3000);
```

The 3000 refers to milliseconds (3 seconds). Change it as required.

See here :
[SetInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: You can simply pass the original function as a delegate:
`setInterval(MyFunctionToDoTheWork, 3000);`

Comment: can I call webapi method in this setinterval func?

Comment: you could do it directly within the setInterval function; however IMHO it would be better to have the call in a separate function and just call the function as in the example. Simply for the sake of clearer coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use javascript setInterval function.